# When is it legal to be recorded? (UK)

Tags: united-kingdom, privacy, recording

The following occurred on private property, no civil servants involved and not illegal.

There was an incident which the other side found funny and they decided to record me without my knowledge.
When I find this out, I ask them to delete the video and photos, which they said they would. **At this point, I have withdrawn my consent**.

I later see their phone and they haven't removed the footage.

Which act covers this, specifically a section so I can look it up on legislation.gov.uk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### When is it legal to be [recorded](https://www.thesun.co.uk/news/4093108/illegal-record-conversation-film-someone/#:%7E:text=The%20rules%20vary%20between%20businesses,a%20conversation%20without%20telling%20someone.&text=If%20you%20sell%20a%20recording,could%20be%20a%20criminal%20offence.)? (UK)

It's pretty much always legal to record someone providing it's not done covertly.

You say the situation occurred on private property - the controller of that property can prohibit or otherwise restrict recording on that property by communication that in *advance*. They cannot require the deletion of recordings that were made while the recorder had permission.

The subject of the recording cannot require deletion either.

Such recordings are only illegal if they are made for a voyeristic sexual purpose without the consent of the subject.